# Call a Specific PHP Function With AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a page that contains come html and php. When I use ajax to call it like so:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'seocond.php',
        data: {
            a: 'a'
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });

});
```

It runs the whole class (alerts everything in the class).

I need it to just run one php function. (Keep in mind that there are a bunch of  tags in this file as well.

Also, is there a way that I can run some jquery code before the actual stuff in the php function is run? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot run a specific php function with ajax you'll only get all the output rendered in HTML format.

Comment: Whats your problem? I can not understand...

Comment: @Andrew Is the problem solved or not???

Answer (score 0):

You can set some parameters to the post like:

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'seocond.php',
        data: {
            a: 'a',
            functionName: 'abc'
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });

});
```

And in the PHP file:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['functionName'] ) && function_exists( $_POST['functionName'] ) )
{
     $funcName = $_POST['functionName'];
     $funcName();
}
```

I hope this makes sense to you.

Answer (score -1):

No. Ajax only lets JavaScript request URLs.

Change the PHP. Write a script which does *only* what you want it to do with the Ajax hits it. Then use the URL to that script in Ajax.

You can use `include`s to share functionality between different PHP scripts.